# QGIS 3.x closestSegmentWithContext returns sqrt distance 0.0 and point doesn't snap to polyline

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3

I have a point and line shapefile.

I am new to QGIS and Python, but have been able to get a working method to snap some of the points to the line. The method I am using is "closestSegmentWithContext", which works where the points are further from the line, but when the points are close (i.e. less than 5-10 meter) it returns a sqrt distance(?) of 0.0, and cannot find the closest point on the line. See for example the below outputs:

```
Var1:  (4.4249768536154936e-08, <QgsPointXY: POINT(27.9118715303157181 -26.09893318956183705)>, 35, 1)
Var2:  (0.0, <QgsPointXY: POINT(27.94594999999999985 -26.09562199999999876)>, 65, -1)
```

With *Var1* I am able to snap the point onto the line, but the *Var2*, the point cannot be snapped onto the line and returns the coordinate of the point.

I am using EPSG:4326 - WSG 84, and I am assuming that the projection is in degrees, although I have set the distance to be in meters in the project settings.

Is there anything that I need to add to my code to get the points to snap onto the line.

Comment: Can you post more of your code? E.g. the linestring you are trying to snap to?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the epsilon value of the closestSegmentWithContext function to a very low value for it to work with lat and long. The DEFAULT_SEGMENT_EPSILON is not low enough to test the values less than 5m.
Try this

```
closestSegmentWithContext(point,0.000000000001)
```